# Setting up key bindings of Corsair Vengeance K70 to work with OS X

Tags: keyboard, macos

I recently purchased a Corsair Vengeance K70 and am trying to get set the `ctrl windows alt` keys to match the ones on a mac keyboard, `control option(alt) command`. Currently the `windows` key acts like `command`.

So far I've tried setting the key bindings by going to `System Preferences -> Modifier Keys -> Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard` and testing different configurations of key settings though this appeared to have no effect.

I also attempted switching the `BIOS switch` on the keyboard though that seemed to have no effect.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

**Update**: By opening the on screen keyboard I can confirm that the problem is that the `windows` key is synced with the `alt` key and `command` with `window` so I need a reliable way to switch those.

Comment: I do not have a solution but will confirm that on a "Windows" keyboard "Control" maps to "Control", "Alt" to "Alt" and "Windows" to "Command". That is the default and I have chosen to leave it like that so when I switch keyboards or computers I will be comfortable with them and not need to change settings or install extra software.

Comment: For some reason the `Modifier Keys` dialog does not tell you to reconnect the keyboard, that is needed also :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) as it seemed to fit my needs and it made it easy to switch the keys. My only complaint is that there is not a per keyboard setting so this also affects my (less used) mac keyboard. Cheers

Comment: Can you explain how you got this to work? I installed DoubleCommand and checked "Option Key acts as Command Key" and also "Command Key acts as Option Key". I clicked activate, System, (put in password), and User. Nothing changed. Then I tried all of the various options and nothing changed.

Comment: @GhostToast With it activated try replugging in your keyboard, I've found I have to do this when switching over key assignments.

Comment: Thanks @bipolarpants. Not to get off topic too much, but I wanted to leave this here as I know others are probably suffering same fate we were. I ended up going with KeyRemap4MacBook as it was easier to get working. There is a GUI for choosing options/keys, one does not have to manually write the XML. While it takes over *every* keyboard (including builtin keyboard on MacBook Pro), it does allow for multiple profiles, so I can easily switch back to "native" keyboard setup when I am unplugged.

Comment: Thanks @GhostToast for the KeyRemap4MacBook. I have a Corsair K70 and this was the only way to get the function keys (F1, F2 etc) to work. The project is now called Karabiner https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me:

1. Open System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Modifier Keys
2. Select the Corsair Vengeance K70 from the Select Keyboard pulldown list
3. Setup your mappings - for me I remapped
4. Ctrl Lock to Control
5. Option to Command
6. Command to Option
7. Close the Keyboard System Preferences
8. Restart the computer (I believe that you can also just close the Preferences unplug the keyboard instead of restart)

After a restart everything worked as expected on Mavericks

Comment: Thanks for this, I had everything here except the restart!

Comment: Unplugging the keyboard was sufficient for me.  No need to restart the computer.

Answer (score 4):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) also supports device-specific settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <devicevendordef>
    <vendorname>KINESIS</vendorname>
    <vendorid>0x05f3</vendorid>
  </devicevendordef>
  <deviceproductdef>
    <productname>ADVANTAGE</productname>
    <productid>0x0007</productid>
  </deviceproductdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <device_only>DeviceVendor::KINESIS, DeviceProduct::ADVANTAGE</device_only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PC_APPLICATION, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

I don't know the vendor or product IDs for Corsair Vengeance K70, but you can see them with EventViewer.app, which is located in `/Applications/KeyRemap4MacBook.app/Contents/Applications/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Karabiner https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/, a keyboard customizer for macOS.

The interface is easy to use and works well.