# Mapping special G-keys in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a Corsair keyboard K95 on OSX High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G5019).

[image]

I already mapped the windows key to make it work as the Command key in osx. Right now i'm trying to map the G-keys (macro keys at the left of the keyboard). Is it possible through an external app? The manufacturer doesn't support drivers for OSX.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to monitor the signals an HID (Human Interface) device sends to the OS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357396/is-there-a-way-to-monitor-the-signals-an-hid-human-interface-device-sends-to-t)

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115874 help?

Comment: @GrahamMiln no quite, that's for remapping via OSX which work for basic keys only.

Comment: It *seems* to be possible with Keyboard Maestro according to https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/corsair-k95-mechanical-keyboard.1951220/, but I don't have a K95 to test this with.

Comment: @nohillside the software seems awesome, but the macro keys are not being detected. I'm gonna research a little more if there is some kind of extra configuration to work around it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you need a Keyboard driver from the manufacturer. However a developer has made a "Universal" USB device driver for the Mac which might do what you need to do. Check out [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html)

**NOTE:** *might*, I have no specific experience with this software, but have heard people using and recommending it for years and years, so I am guessing it will work for you.

Comment: I installed it, but more keys stopped working, and there was no way to activate the macro keys. Thanks anyways.